# How to pass multipart/related request in Mule?

Tags: mule, multipart

I want to request an API using Mule.It is using Multipart/related Content-Type to upload a file.I Don't know how to pass the boundary information in mule.How to set the given input in a payload to send to HTTP.I tried to put it in a transform Message component but it showing errors.
[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the outbound attachments collection to create the form parts as necessary, and don't need to specify the boundary.

For example, consider the following Mule configuration:

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
  <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
    message.addOutboundAttachment('some-json.json', '{ "name": "My File" }', 'application/json');
    message.addOutboundAttachment('myfile.txt', new java.io.File('c:\\myfile.txt'), null);
  ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

The outbound HTTP request which Mule issues is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:80
User-Agent: AHC/1.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=pHSj1qavizuHBv879Hoo_RQ9tFqtAfS9i;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 438

--pHSj1qavizuHBv879Hoo_RQ9tFqtAfS9i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="some-json.json"
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

{ "name": "My File" }
--pHSj1qavizuHBv879Hoo_RQ9tFqtAfS9i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile.txt"; filename="myfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

This is just some random text file...

--pHSj1qavizuHBv879Hoo_RQ9tFqtAfS9i--
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can I pass  BufferInputStream object as a FileContent. Beacuse I am not uploading file from local system.

Comment: You should just be able to replace the `new File(...)` statement with your stream in the example above. From memory I believe it can handle this. Note also that you don't need to use Groovy/script code to do this, there is an Attachment transformer in the Mule Palette.